# Docker container Net I/O limit

Tags: docker, networking, containers

I need to stop data transfer of my docker containers when traffic usage exceeds an amount.
Let's say I have a container and the limit is 50GB. So I need to stop automatically container when NET I/O Usage reaches 50 GB.

I can read the network trrafic usage of all containers with python and close a container when it reaches the limit but I want to do it with docker commands or other approach.